# what is currently the easiest way to properly change the bundle id for android in a RN app?

Tags: react-native

What is currently the easiest way to properly change the bundle id for android in a RN app?  Changing the bundle ID for ios is super simple.  Just go to the General tab in the xcode project and update the "Bundle Identifier" input.

But, from what I understand, updating the budle id for android is not as straightforward, and I've seen people refer to a few different ways to do it.  So what is the latest and greatest recommended way to properly change the bundle id for android in a RN app?

Comment: do a search for the existing name and see what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you want to change manually these information. In Android, you can go to your **build.gradle** file in your **app** folder.

You should see something like this :

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project" // Your "bundle id" for Android
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 32
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }
}
```